# Angular $window.location.assign to hashtag doesn't load inside controller

Tags: angularjs

When I set `$window.location.assign('#/someurl');` in a controller I can see the hashtag change, but it doesn't load.

```
.when("/signin", {
        templateUrl: templateSource+"/signin",
        controller: function($scope, $location, $window){
              $window.location.assign('#/checkout/billing');
        }
})
```

Comment: can you not use `$location.path()`?

Comment: or use `window`, not `$window`

Answer (score 0):

use `window`, not `$window` or use `$location.path('#/checkout/billing');`

```
.when("/signin", {
    templateUrl: templateSource+"/signin",
    controller: function($scope, $location){
        $location.path('#/checkout/billing');
    }
})
```

Comment: It looks like the path sets the characters to: %23%2Fcheckout%2Fbilling